# ios, publish different build per device

Tags: ios, app-store, publishing

**Google Play** allows different `apks` per screen density, does **Apple Store** support this?

- I'm sure the info is somewhere, but all I find when I search are people asking how to develop one app to support all devices.
- I know how to do that already, but this specific (top secret) project will be 1000 times better if I can release one super optimized version for each **screen resolution**... but I'll settle for density or device (generation and type) if needed.

I don't have access to `XCode` (no `Mac`) to check options currently.

**Bonus points:** If possible, is Apple going to frown on this and possibly reject my app because of this?

Comment: You can check the screen resolution at run time.  But... the best option is to just develop for the highest resolution device you plan to support... in iOS there's really no point in releasing a completely different code base for each resolution.  I can't imagine any reason why you'd need to "super optimize" for the different iOS resolutions...

Comment: I hope that downvote isn't somehow who thinks they know everything and thinks I'm dumb.. I have my reasons for wanting this, but why do I need to make my post even longer explaining that?

Comment: Have you done ANY iOS development?  This question comes across and putting the cart way, way, way in front of the horse.

Comment: I have published 2 apps to the app store, business apps though and they did support all devices with one build.  My current project is a game though, and is new to me.  I don't want to include HD graphics in a build that someone might install on a 1G device though, I don't hate my users that much.

Comment: You can't not include the graphics on some devices but not on others (unless you download them after install), but you can include an HD and non-HD image and load the correct one based on device specs.

Comment: My "I know how to do that already" was supposed to avoid people thinking I didn't already know how to do that... I could have worded it better though, I've been staying up too late lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done. If your app supports the iPhone then it must support both 4" and 3.5" inch iPhones. If it supports only iOS 7 then you can avoid non-retina devices because only retina devices can run iOS 7.

But if you support the iPad you must support both retina and non-retina.

You can have one app (Universal) that does it all or you can have separate iPhone and separate iPad apps. But the iPhone app must support both sizes and possibly both types (retina and non-retina) of screens. And the iPad app must support both types of screens.

Apple won't accept apps that don't support the differences.

Comment: While this is true, a single app could be coded to run a completely different code base, storyboard, everything, based on a quick check on some hardware at launch.  It'd be one app as far as the app store or Apple is concerned, but could easily be a specific different code base for each resolution, etc.

Comment: That's an implementation detail. It's still 1 or 2 apps, not several.

Comment: Thanks, I feared this but wanted to confirm, since still in my design part of project.  Does make me wonder how an app could be updated to support new APIs but still be installed on older devices, but maybe that just isn't possible.

Comment: Of course it can. I have apps that support iOS 5 through 7. It uses newer APIs when possible. Apple has a whole document on supporting multiple version in a single app. See the "SDK Compatibility Guide".

Answer (score 0):

It should also be pointed out that in the Interface Builder part of Xcode, you setup the UI with points and not pixels.  So, for an iPad, when you place a button, you do not have to specify retina or not.  On a Retina screen a point is 2x2 pixels and on a non-retina screen a point is 1x1 pixels.  Also, with image assets, you have a single image asset you ask for in code, but you add multiple copies of the image in the image assets.  Like the retina and non-retina copies.  If you have an image named cat.png, for retina this would be cat@2x.png and for non-retina it would be cat.png.  But, in code or the inspector you would reference it with    imageNamed:@"cat" and Objective-C is designed to handle the rest.